# Problemas métodos de arreglos C#

Tags: c#, array

Hola he estado intentando regresar un valor de un método que realice, pero no estoy seguro si funciona ya cree un objeto de su clase pero no se como comprobar si regresa los valores dados, es un arreglo en c# ( cree otro metodo para que el array que retorna este mismo metodo lo tome como parametro ) son ejercicios de mi escuela.

```
public string[] Array()
    {

        string[] arry;

        int x = 5;

        arry = new string[x];

        for (int i = 0; i != 5; i++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Escribe nombre " + (i + 1));
            arry[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("");


        }

        return arry;



    }
```

segundo metodo

```
 public void imp(string[] ay )
    {


        for (int i = 0; i != 5; i++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Impresion del arreglo ");

            Console.WriteLine(ay);


        }


    }
```

Comment: soy nuevo en c# , ya cree los objetos y en vez de imprimir los valores del arreglo me imprime "Syste.string[]"

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que imprimir cada elemento del arreglo
también te recomendaría cambiar el `i !=5`  por `i < 5`
también podrías cambiar el for por un while y seguir utilizando el `i !=5`
Suele ser mas convencional.

```
 public void imp(string[] ay )
    {


        for (int i = 0; i != 5; i++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Impresion del arreglo: ");

            Console.WriteLine(ay[i]);


        }


    }
```

Comment: Gracias, saludos amigo!

Comment: Hola @eraser99, bienvenid@ a [es.so] te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad. También recuerda marcar una respuesta como válida si te ha resultado últil.

Answer (score 0):

Para el segundo metodo deberia ser asi :

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int ay = 0; ay != 5; ay++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Impresion del arreglo");
    }
    }
```

Por que me imagino que quieres imprimir el mensaje en el ciclo for. ESpero te sirva este ejemplo, si entendi mal, dimelo.